# Prefill values from PHP session in form field (registration form buddypress) - HOW?

Tags: php, forms, session-variables, populate, buddypress

tried all I could find so far, at no avail :-(

I have some values (like "name", "prename", "gendre") stored in a php session.

I now want to prefill a form (the buddypress registration form with extra fields to be more precise) with those values.

So I have so far:

```
<?php 

$field_1 = $_POST['Name'];
$field_5 = $_POST['Prename']; 
$field_7 = $_POST['gendre']; 

?>
```

And in the form, the field I need to prefill (dynamically) looks like that:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php bp_the_profile_field_input_name() ?>" id="<?php bp_the_profile_field_input_name() ?>" value="<?php bp_the_profile_field_edit_value() ?>">
```

So the problem is that the field is dynamically generated, so I have to somehow loop through those values (field_1, field_5 etc) to get the appropriate field prefilled with the appropriate value (pulled from that session).

I really have no clue how should I modify  `value="<?php bp_the_profile_field_edit_value() ?>` to get the right values.

Or any other method out there :)

Please be so kind and post the example / code as I am not a programmer, so I understand v. little from general explanations :-(

Thank you!

Comment: you did fine, only that the ID-tag and the NAME-tag I would choose as id1, id2, id3... name1, name2, name3...

Comment: I am not sure I understand ... the "filed_1, field_2 etc" are the way those dynamically generated values look like. So the name="<?php bp_the_profile_field_input_name() ?>" automatically generates the name fields called exactely that: field_1, field_200 etc. Cannot change that :-(. And my problem is how to insert the values in the fields, because till now, nothing worked ... :-(

Comment: you can do it (in the example you gave) with: `value="<?php echo $field_1; ?>`

Comment: hmm, yes, but that will only give the value of field_1 and I need smth. like value="<?php echo $some_variable_to_dynamically_output_the_field_names" ?>. As I said, the fields are generated automatically by a script so the same bit of php code outputs a bunch of fields. In the code I only have this bit: <input type="text" name="<?php bp_the_profile_field_input_name() ?> value="<?php bp_the_profile_field_edit_value() ?>" and this is outputing all those fields (field_1,filed_100) dynamically. I can't replace the field values one by one, that's my problem ...

Comment: That's why I said I would stick to ID1, ID2 etc, cause this way you can use only one counter, `$i`, and concatenate it to every variable: `name=somename$i` or  `id=ID$i` and then you can use an associative array of fields and call `$fields[$i]`. How do you read all these fields as POST parameters if the number of fields is dynamic ?

Comment: yes but it's the buddypress core script who's generating the field names that way, I cannot change that :-( and have no idea about arrays :-( I am not a programmer, just struggling to find a solution to this somehow :-( It does not help that the field names have the same structure like field_1 ..field_200 ? Can't that be used like `name="field_" . $i ` ?!? Just guessing here, never wrote a bit of php myself .. :-(

Comment: yes, you can do it with `name="field_" . $i`

Comment: so .. what code should I write now and where ?!? I tried some googling, but did not come any further .. :-( Thanks so much!

Comment: Anyone can please help!??! It's one month at least I try to solve this puzzle .. I thought for a php specialist this is a little trick, still nobody seems to know the answer !??!?!

Comment: you didn't answer my question: How do you read all these fields as POST parameters if the number of fields is dynamic ? I asked that - cause you'll need to implement the same mechanism with the tags.

Comment: the issue is as as I already mentioned I am not a programmer, so many of these very technical questions are a bit like chinese for me :-( So in short, I would love to answer, but I really do not understand the question :-( . In the session I only have 4 fields saved (Name, Prename, Company, email) coming from a different page/form, and on the present page I need to prefill only those 4 values in the respective fields (filed_1 for Name, field_5 for prename, field_20 for company, email for email. The rest of the fields which are dynamically generated by that form can stay empty. Does this help?

Comment: not really sorry. It requires diving into the code and see what's going on. You need to find yourself a PHP programmer that will work with you.

Comment: so, you say that it's a terribly complicated thing to pass variables from one form into an other? THis is the classical buddypress registration form `http://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.2.7/bp-themes/bp-default/registration/register.php`` ... and I need to pass the above mentioned 4 values into that "textbox" ...

Comment: I'm not saying it's `terribly complicated`. I'm saying that if you want to pass parameters which have dynamic names/ids it requires more effort than just submitting a form. This one has 300 lines of code and this is a work that needs to be done - not a question to be answered.

Comment: well, the form might have 300 lines of code, but the only one I'd need  altered is line 69 (the "value" field respectively). The rest of the code is in my view irrelevant to my issue ... I actually don't want to pass 100 values, just 3 and they all connect only to line 69 in that long php file .... Is there really no way to grab the values from the session in form of $_SESSION['here_is_my_problem'] and echo that inside the "value" field of line 69 ?!

Comment: Maybe it was not clear, but the passed parameters have no dynamic ids, just the damned (sorry) fields in the "catching" form do ... (line 69 in the long php file). So my parameters are already stored in the session in the form Name, Prename, Company. Just trying to "catch" them up on a page containing a form which unfortunatelly contains those dynamically generated form fields (line 69) ...